# installation - PHP Extensions "pdo_mysql" must be loaded

Tags: magento

This is whay i see on phpinfo();

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  5.1.68

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

but im still getting the magento message :
"PHP Extensions "pdo_mysql" must be loaded"

why is that ?

Comment: What OS are you using? If linux what distribution? Also see http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=27756

Comment: CENTOS 6.4 x86_64 vmware

Comment: Is your php version 5.4?

Answer (score 0):

open or make `php.ini` file into root directory and add the following code:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```